# Generalized Poincare conjecture, 4D differentiable case

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I recently learnt that the current status of Poincare conjecture:

Top: All true

PL: All true except n=4 being unknown

Diff: True for n=1,2,3,5,6,12; unknown for n=4; False for everything else

Question 1: Is what I learnt correct?

Question 2: Did people try this with the infinite dimensional manifolds? Are fractional dimensional manifolds being defined and studied?

Comment: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hilbert_manifold#Specialties_of_Infinite_Dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Question 1:* From the Wikipedia article on the [Generalized Poincare Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture), this is correct :

*Question 2: Part(a)* There are infinite-dimensional manifolds called "[Banach Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold)". However I'm not sure if any work has been done regarding a similar conjecture for these infinite-dimensional manifolds.

*Question 2: Part (b)* The definition of a topological manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ is a Haursdoff space, together with the added condition that for every point $x \in M$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \subseteq M$ of $x$, hoemomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Remember $\mathbb{R}^n$ is just the cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ taken $n$ times, that is $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R} \times ... \times \mathbb{R} $ ($n$ times). An element $x$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is of the form $x = (x_1, x_2, ...., x_n)$. Hence $\mathbb{R}^{\frac{m}{n}}$, doesn't even make sense, for example what does an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\frac{m}{n}}$ even look like?

Because $\mathbb{R}^{\frac{m}{n}}$ isn't even defined, we can't have a topological manifold $M$ of dimension $\frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: Homeomorphic Hilbert manifolds are necessarily diffeomorphic, see http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hilbert_manifold#Specialties_of_Infinite_Dimension.

Comment: Thanks. The n=12 case is not stated on the wiki site. But I believe it is correct.

Comment: Yes it's true that there are no exotic spheres in $12$ dimensions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere